# Text isn't showing when I add another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show text right side to image and I was successful to made it but when I add another div for border the text doesn't show up, it's like invisible but still taking its space I tried but I can't figure out the problem here you can see the live preview https://jsfiddle.net/Ldu91at2/ And here is the code before adding a main div for border:-

```
<div  style="display:inline-block; min-width:6.2cm; height:8.8cm; align: center;vertical-align: middle;" >
    
  <img src="https://www.asurascans.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/56953.jpg" style="height:100%;">
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align: top;">
  <span id="title">advertishement</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: "I want to show text right side to image": `float:right`

Comment: @mardubbles plz check the https://jsfiddle.net/Ldu91at2/

Comment: `.cont` in css is affecting the text color. use browser inspect to find the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the css style you are using for the .cont div

```
.cont{
    width:fit-content;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
 }
```

The

> color: #fff;

rule makes your text white thus invisible against a white background. Consider removing it or using a different color. The code below will work.

```
   .cont{
    width:fit-content;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 10px;
 }
```

Comment: Yo bro can you help on another thing? Like the text isn't responsive I want it to be break according to div width but it's not breaking

Comment: @GaitoUchiha sorry for the late reply. I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want the text to fit the with of the div or? You can check the answer provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410627/auto-sizing-width-with-fit-content-in-css

Comment: It's solved now bro thanks for replying

Comment: Now I am stucked in cors issue do you know any way to prevent it?

Comment: @GaitoUchiha can you post your error and what exactly you are trying to do so I can reproduce the error from my end

Comment: Already posted a question plz take a look https://stackoverflow.com/q/71814914/18445889